# Hibernate Search, am I doing it right?

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I have an Entity which I wish to index using Hibernate search to take advantage of the full textual search functionality. The Entity has several fields on which I need to filter. As an example:

```
@Field(index = Index.TOKENIZED, store = Store.NO)
@Lob
private String description;

@Field(index = Index.UN_TOKENIZED, store = Store.NO)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@NotNull
private Type type;
```

The `description` field is what I want to use the full textual search on. The `Type` field I just want to do a plain old match against. It feels slightly wrong to me that Lucene should be dealing with straight up matching on top of doing the full textual search, and I should be using something like `CriteriaBuilder` to handle the additional filtering. However, I cannot find any way to combine the two and am resorting to using `BooleanJunction` operators in my search algorithm with `must`, `matching`, and `keyword` on the fields that I need to straight up match.

So my question, am I doing it right or should I only be using Lucene for full textual search and do the filtering of other attributes some other way?

Many thanks,
Finbarr

Answer (score 1):

@Finbarr, my suggestion would be to just use Hibernate Search for this. I would recommend that to filter your results by type you should use a Hibernate Search [FullTextFilter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.4/reference/en-US/html/search-query.html#query-filter) and enable the filter on your FullTextQuery that searches through "description" just before you execute this query. I can post an example for you if the docs aren't sufficient, I have used these filters often and they work very well.

Comment: I am trying to use the [DuplicateFilter of Lucene on Hibernate Search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595943/duplicatefilter-in-hibernate-search), but still couldn't find a way to do it. It would be great if you could help on this. thanks