# DuplicateFilter in Hibernate Search

Tags: filter, lucene, hibernate-search

I know there is a built-in DuplicateFilter in Lucene, to deduplicate the results from lucene. This is a very important feature for the users to search on the document database, where duplicating rate is very high.

As I am using Hibernate Search to do the full text index/search, and wondering if there is a way for me bring the DuplicateFilter on Lucene to the Hibernate Search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible by using [filters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#query-filter). See for `BestDriversFilter` - it extends [org.apache.lucene.search.Filter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Filter.html?is-external=true) in the same way as [DuplicateFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/sandbox/org/apache/lucene/sandbox/queries/DuplicateFilter.html).

Comment: Is there any reason why the DuplicateFilter cannot be used directly?